# Issue with UISearchController in UITableView on iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios11, uisearchcontroller

**iOS 11** I'm having a `UITableViewController` with a `UISearchController` on the table's headerview using the following code :

```
if(searchController == nil)
{
    searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = NO;
    searchController.delegate = self;
}
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar;

[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,searchController.searchBar.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
```

When I run the app, the behavior I want is perfectly working for the `tableview` with rows more than the height of the device screen but on the case of `tableview` having only a few number of rows, the search bar is dropping a little bit down from the navigation bar.

[When there are few cells on the tableview, the search bar drops down as in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So70h.png)

[When there are more cells on the tableview, the search bar doesn't drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udwdi.png)

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 11 the behaviour of UISearchController with tableView header has changed, now it a part of the navigationItem and you dont need the tableView. So you must check if iOS >= 11 and do the following

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController;
// ToDo : dont forget to hide the tableView 
// ...       
} else {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar;
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,searchController.searchBar.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I'm having a requirement that I have to use the search on the tableview header only. That's why I'm seeking a way to do it.

Comment: its a very bad idea, you will have a lot of troubles with iOS 11 and especially  iPhone X ...

Comment: @AbidMohamedSadok  , Have you got this working. In ios 11 if is in navigation item(part of navigation bar ) then what if i need navigation title +search bar as a table header?